# Why python doesn't read the environment variable and can't run a windows command line?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, command-line, appium, python-appium

I am trying to run the appium server from my python 3.7 code.
So I use this simple line of code:

```
os.system("start /B start cmd.exe @cmd /k appium")
```

I see the command windows pop up and give the error "appium' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

But I checked my environment variable and they are fine. I can even run appium from command by hand from same folder. Please check the screenshot as a prove:

[image]

So what I am doing wrong? Doesn't anyone can help me please?

Comment: The command line `cmd.exe /c start /B start cmd.exe @cmd /k appium` is convoluted, and `cmd.exe @cmd /k appium` is definitely wrong. Use subprocess instead, e.g. `p = subprocess.Popen('appium', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)`.

Comment: Thank you. But I get error : FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]

Comment: In the command prompt, run `where appium` to find its fully-qualified path. Either run it with the full path, or add the directory to the user or system `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks @ErykSun , but as my explanation said: PATH environment variable is already setup. That is the issue!

Comment: Telling us that `PATH` is setup correctly is not showing us that claim. I've seen lots of mistakes made, such as using double quotes in `PATH` entries. This is wrong and will cause a general `SearchPathW` to fail, as is used by `CreateProcessW` and thus `subprocess.Popen` with `shell=False`. It happens to work via the CMD shell (i.e. `shell=True`), but the proper resolution is to fix `PATH`, not to rely on undocumented behavior of an ancient shell when processing a malformed `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, this is the command which fix my issue:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('npm install -g appium',shell=True,stdin=None, stdout=True, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
```